# UIView added as subview to the Application Window does not rotate when the device rotates

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, rotation

I had created an extension to the `UIView` and created an `ActivityIndicatorView` and added it as the subview to `UIApplication` `Window`. Now when the device rotates the `UIViewController` also rotates and not this `ActivityIndicatorView`.

```
internal extension UIView{

func showActivityViewWithText(text: String?) -> UIView{

    let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window!!
    let baseLineView = window!.viewForBaselineLayout()

    let locView = UIView(frame:window!.frame)
    locView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    locView.center = window!.center

    baseLineView.addSubview(locView)
    baseLineView.bringSubviewToFront(locView)

    let overlay = UIView(frame: locView.frame)
    overlay.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    overlay.alpha = 0.35

    locView.addSubview(overlay)
    locView.bringSubviewToFront(overlay)

    let hud = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .WhiteLarge)
    hud.hidesWhenStopped = true
    hud.center = CGPoint(x: locView.frame.size.width/2,
                         y: locView.frame.size.height/2)

    hud.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1)
    hud.color = UIColor.redColor()
    hud.startAnimating()

    locView.addSubview(hud)
    locView.bringSubviewToFront(hud)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be problem is in missed autoresizing mask? Try to add:

```
hud.autoresizingMask = [ .flexibleTopMargin, .flexibleBottomMargin, .flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleRightMargin ]
```

In a reason your `hud` is subview of a `locView` `autoresizingMask` is required for `locView` too I suppose.

Comment: Adding `autoresizingMask` to `locView` did it. Thanks.